# Explain time and space complexity of two python codes. Which one is the best? (Non- subjective)

Tags: python, time, complexity-theory, space

These codes gives the sum of even integers in a list without using loop statement. I would like to know the time complexity and space complexity of both codes. which is best?

CODE 1:

```
class EvenSum:
     #Initialize the class

    def __init__(self):
        self.res = 0

    def sumEvenIntegers(self, integerlist):
        if integerlist:
            if not integerlist[0] % 2: 
                self.res += integerlist[0]
                del integerlist[0]
                self.sumEvenIntegers(integerlist)
            else:
                del integerlist[0]
                self.sumEvenIntegers(integerlist)
        return self.res

#main method
if __name__ == "__main__":
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
even = EvenSum()
print even.sumEvenIntegers(l)
```

CODE 2:

```
import numpy as np

def sum_of_all_even_integers(list):
    list_sum = sum(list)  
    bin_arr  = map(lambda x:x%2, list)
    return list_sum - sum(list*bin_arr)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    list = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
    print sum_of_all_even_integers(list)
```

Comment: I think asking for the "best" is subjective. Do you want the most memory efficient, or time efficient? You should update your question to be non-subjective.

Comment: Why function `sum_of_elements` in code 2?

Comment: `sum(value for value in data if not value % 2)`

Comment: Just adding *"non-subjective"* to the title doesn't make it so; what are your **objective criteria**?

Comment: I am new to python, i am not familiar using keywords in stack overflow, "subjective" or "non-subjective". Here for this question, the objective to know the complexities of both codes where i can write code with out using loop to sum even integers in a list. if there is any mistake in framing question, apologize me.

Comment: This isn't really related to Stack Overflow or Python, but the meaning of words in the English language. Get a dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), deleting an item from a list takes linear time proportional to the number of elements in the list. Since you delete every item in the list, and each deletion takes linear time, the overall runtime is proportional to the square of number of items in the list.

In your second code snippet, both `sum` as well as `map` take linear time. So the overall complexity is linear proportional to the number of elements in the list. Interestingly, `sum_of_elements` isn't used at all (but it doesn't sum all even elements either).

Answer (score 1):

First code use item deletion in list and recursivity, two thing at which python is not so good : time deletion take an O(n) time, since you recreate the whole list, and python does not optimize recursive calls (to keep full info about the traceback I think).

So I would go for the second code (which I think actually use "for loops", only the loops are hidden in the `reduce` and `map`).

If you use numpy, you could actually do something like :

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
np.sum(np.where((a+1)%2,a,0))
```

Or like anki proposed :

```
np.sum( a[a%2 == 0] )
```

Which I think would be best since numpy is optimized for array manipulation.

By the way, never name an object `list`, as it overwrites the list constructor.

EDIT :

If you just want the sum of all even number in [0,n], you don't need a sum or anything. There is a mathematical formula for that :

```
 s=(n//2)*(n//2+1)
```

Comment: `np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])` is a very slow operation though.

Comment: `np.arange` would be better, sure, but I guess he just use it as an example. You don't actually need a sum at all to compute the sum of even number from 1 to n, since there is an exact formula.

Comment: Thank you, Nihl. Is there code else to do  sum of even integers in a list without using predefined python packages (numpy or sum), just using +.  which still holds O(N) time, space.

Comment: A list comprehension : `sum([x for x in a if x%2==0])`

Comment: but not using any loop statements

Comment: Why ? Any code you could come up will most certainly be using a loop statement, just not explicitly stated. You can use `reduce(lambda x,y: x + (y if y%2==0 else 0), [0] + a)`, but it is not clear (and PEP recommendations discourage this kind of code), and actually contains a loop, just hidden behind the Python syntax.

Answer (score 1):

what about the following?

```
import numpy as np    
a = np.arange(20)
print np.sum(a[a%2==0])
```

It seems to be much more lightweight compared to your two code snippets.

Small timings with an `np.arange(998)`:

```
Pure numpy:
248502
0.0
Class recursion:
248502
0.00399994850159
List/Numpy one: 
248502
0.00200009346008
```

And, if there's a 999 element array, your class runs in failure, because the maximum recursion depth is reached.

Answer (score 0):

First have `O(N^2)` time complexity and `O(N)` space complexity. The second  have `O(N)` time complexity and space complexity.

The first uses one stack frame (one piece of stack memory of constant but quite large size) for each element in the array. In addition it executes the function for each element, but for each time it deletes the first element of the array, which is an `O(N)` operation.

The second happens much behind the scene. The `map` function generates a new list of the same size of the original, in addition it calls a function for each element - giving the complexity directly. Similarily for the `reduce` and `sum` functions - they do the same operation for each element in the list, although they don't use more memory than constant. Adding up these doesn't make the complexities worse - twice or thrice `O(N)` is still `O(N)`.

The best is probably the later, but then again - it depends on what your preferences are. Maybe you want to consume a lot of time and stack space? In that case the first would suit your preferences much better.

Also note that the first solution modifies the input data - they don't do the same thing in other words. After calling the first the list sent to the function would be empty (which may or may not be a bad thing).